# A periodic in x, Lipschitz in y, ODE with a periodic initial condition must have a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to check if my reasoning is correct as this question was a bit different than what I previously encountered :

**Question**

> Suppose :
>
> 1. The well-posed ODE is periodic in $x$ with period $T$ : $\forall x \in \Re : y'(x) = F(x,y) = F(x+T,y)$
> 2. The initial condition is also periodic with period $T$ : $y(a) = y(a+T) = Y$
>
> If $u(x)$ is the unique solution, then $\forall x \in \Re :u(x) = u(x+T)$

**Working**

Since the ODE is well-posed then there exists a unique solution, call it $u(x)$.

Another way to write the given ODE is : $$u(x) = Y + \int_a^x F(x,u) dx$$

Shift $x$ by $T$ : $z = x + T$ and hence $F(z,u) = F(x,u)$ **and** $u(a)$ translates to (and is equal to) $u(a-T)$.

Therefore $dz = dx$ which by substitution gives :
$$u(x) = u(z-T) = Y + \int_{a+T}^{x+T} F(z,u)dz = Y + \int_{a+T}^{x+T} F(x,u)dx$$
$$\therefore u(x) = Y + \int_{a+T}^{x+T} F(x,u)dx = Y + \int_a^x F(x,u) dx$$

Clearly $u(x)$ is periodic with period $T$.

**Comment**

I'm not entirely sure this is correct throughout, mainly how I handled the initial point. Is this idea correct or salvageable? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What if $F$ is a non-zero constant?

Comment: @HansEngler I see. This doesn't seem right at all then. Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Wait a second, in that case the initial point of the solution itself cannot be periodic, so this result would not apply. Am I right?

Comment: What does it mean to say that the initial condition is periodic?

Comment: @copper.hat In the question statement, I'm given that for the initial point $(a, y(a))$ we have : $y(a) = y(a + T) = Y$, the same period that $F(x, y)$ is periodic with.
I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you mean by initial solution as opposed to an initial condition.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah that's my mistake, sorry.